# Возможен ли переход по якорям на странице без ссылок а?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня кнопка "вверх" http://joxi.ru/Y2LqlnGu3P0wA6 сделана ссылкой:

```
<div class="to-top col-md-2 col-sm-4">
    <a href="#top" class="btn">Наверх</a>
</div>
```

Я оптимизирую страницу для SEO продвижения, и хотелось бы убрать все пустые ссылки.

Вот чего хотелось бы:

```
<div class="to-top col-md-2 col-sm-4">
    <span data-target="top" class="btn">Наверх</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `onclick='window.scroll(0,0)'` не подойдёт?

Comment: Подошел бы, однако скриптов открытых на странице не должно быть! все должно быть в файлах, вот бы перевести, то что вы сказали в файл.

Answer (score 3):

```js
for(const el of document.querySelectorAll('*[data-target]')){
    const target = document.querySelector(`*[data-ankor="${el.dataset.target}"]`);
    el.addEventListener('click', e => target.scrollIntoView(true));
}
```

```html
<div class="to-top col-md-2 col-sm-4">
    <span data-target="top" class="btn">Туда</span>
</div>
<div class="to-top col-md-2 col-sm-4">
    <span data-ankor="top" class="btn">Сюда</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо комментаторам за ответы, на основе их я нарыл хороший пример той прокрутке, которую я желал:

```
$(function(){
    $('#to-top-btn').on('click', function(e){
        $('html,body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $('body').offset().top }, 1000);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```